# Excel time changes to previous day after copy/pasting from an equation

Tags: excel, datetime, copy-paste

I have an issue with copy/pasting datetime information in Excel. I have a sheet where I need to create hourly datetime values for some price analysis, and the calculations themselves work just fine; it adds an hour to each previous hour as I would expect.

The issue is that when it comes to the 12am time specifically, the cell will say, for instance 1/2/19 12:00 AM, but the formula bar will show 1/1/2019  12:00:00 AM. I don't really care what the formula bar says, but that appears to be the value Excel is actually using. If I copy/paste:value the date and then compute copy-pasted it equals exactly 1.

So to summarize, my formulas to calculate datetime are fine on the surface, but for some reason the actual values differ from what is shown and what should actually be the value.

I'm using Excel 2016.

I honestly don't know where to start with the formula bar problem, but I have tried copy/pasting in almost any way imaginable, both by changing formats of the 'copy area' and the 'paste area', even formatting as text then formatting back to date.

I think something that's interesting is when I paste the datetime in, it initially shows the correct date in the cell, but when I hit f2 on the cell is switches to the previous day; right time, wrong day.

I'll try to upload the file if I can.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably a workbook demonstrating the problem would be best. I cannot reproduce your problem.  If my worksheet cell shows `1/2/2019 12:00 AM`, the formula bar shows `1/2/2019 12:00:00 AM`  And, of course, you chose to not show the equation.

Comment: Thanks for the snarky reply Ron. I was trying to figure out if I could attach my workbook, per my notes, but didn't have enough time to figure it out as this is my first post.I was able to figure it out today, while I don't know why the displays were different, I found that when using the time() function, if entering time(24,,) you get a 0 value, so I just switched it to cell/24.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. But when someone posts a question that does not include enough information to reproduce the problem, the question may get downvoted and even closed (or maybe a snarky comment from a frustrated contributor having a bad day). In your case, the formula you were using might (or might not) have provided an avenue for advice. Some guidelines for the forum are outlined in the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. While I still don't know why the displays were different, I found that when using the `time()` function, if entering `time(24,,)` you get a 0 value, so I just switched it to `(hour/24)`.